# How to merge columns from a database table in talend?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, talend

I have a table in my database which contains addresses. There are separate fields for street number, unit number, street name, street direction, and province. I want to merge all these columns into one in order to make a single address, and then compare it with the incoming addresses from a CSV data file. If the addresses match, then assign them the same address id as in the database table for the respective addresses.

I am new to talend, and I'm not sure how to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Talend.

However, how about creating a **view** (in the database) which would present the address as you wanted, and then compare view's `ADDRESS` column to the CSV file? Something like this (mostly blindly guessing as I have no idea what columns you mentioned really represent):

This is a table you currently have:

```
SQL> select * from address;

STREET_NUMBER UNIT_NUMBER STREET_NAME STREE PROVINC
------------- ----------- ----------- ----- -------
            1           2 Main street North Central
            2           2 Zara street South West
```

Create a view; its `full_address` column format should match the CSV file's value as close as possible. I probably failed to do so, but - as you didn't provide any sample data, I hope that the idea itself will be a good starting point:

```
SQL> create or replace view v_address as
  2    select street_number,
  3           unit_number,
  4           -- concatenate next 3 columns
  5           street_name ||', '|| street_direction ||', '|| province as full_addres
  6    from address;

View created.

SQL> select * From v_address;

STREET_NUMBER UNIT_NUMBER FULL_ADDRESS
------------- ----------- ---------------------------
            1           2 Main street, North, Central
            2           2 Zara street, South, West

SQL>
```

Finally, you'd compare `full_address` to CSV file's values.

Comment: Actually its a college assignment and I'm not allowed to add anything to the database which is out of the assignment tasks.

Comment: No problem either. Code I used for a view, you'd use as a CTE or an inline view.